# Connect Azure Log Analytics to Azure Metrics with ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

The collection of Azure metrics in OMS is quite simple through the portal. I would like to create that connection during deployment in an ARM template, but I cannot find anything in regard. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
In my case I am looking to integrate the metrics of IoT-Hub - specially the latencies. But I think this is a general question since OMS allows to integrate a lot of different metrics for a lot of resources and the process should be the same.

Comment: which metrics for which resource?

Comment: @Pizzamaka Do you check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/oms-azure-storage-analytics-solution).

Comment: @Walter-MSFT: Thank you for the link. But I think I meant something else: In the portal I can add a resource through "Work Space Datasources"->"Azure Resources". I would like to put this in my ARM Template.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer is, that it is not possible through ARM-Templates, but must be done through PowerShell. In my case (for Iot Hub) I used the following command after the deployment of the ARM-Templates:

```
Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $iotHubId -WorkspaceId $opsInsightsWorkspaceId -Enabled $true
```

Comment: this is not correct, this can be do through arm template

Comment: It was at the time of writing :-) Now you are right: it can be set using ARM-templates.

Comment: thats not true, unless you have any evidence to back it up

Comment: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-logs-stream-template) - just tested it successfully.

Comment: this doesnt prove it is not possible with arm template,it proves the reverse

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding: What I said in the post ist that it's **not** possible with ARM. In the comments I stated **it is** possible. That's what I proved.

Comment: exactly, you said its not possible with arm, which makes no sense, because everything is an arm request, more or less